# How should be the request import logic between system?

Tags: sap-gui, sap-r3

I'm changing a report source code in DEV system and transporting request to QA system to test the report. Assume that I have many requests include only one object that I've transported from DEV to QA for testing the report after making changes in same program.

Requests imported to QA are like:

```
 1037   ABDK923094   400        MTOK   Z_SAMPLE BUG_FIX 1
 1038   ABDK923098   400        MTOK   Z_SAMPLE BUG_FIX 2
 1039   ABDK923100   400        MTOK   Z_SAMPLE BUG_FIX 3
 1040   ABDK923100   400        MTOK   Z_SAMPLE BUG_FIX 4
 1041   ABDK923100   400        MTOK   Z_SAMPLE BUG_FIX 5
 1042   ABDK923100   400        MTOK   Z_SAMPLE BUG_FIX 6
 1043   ABDK923100   400        MTOK   Z_SAMPLE BUG_FIX 7
 1044   ABDK923100   400        MTOK   Z_SAMPLE BUG_FIX 8
 1045   ABDK923100   400        MTOK   Z_SAMPLE BUG_FIX 9
```

They all have one same object;

```
 LIMU   REPS    Z_SAMPLE
```

Now I want to transport all the requests to Production system from QA.

Should I transport all the request one by one from QA to Production or delete all the requests but the last one and transport only the last request to PROD (for clearing the unnecessary requests)?

Which one is more appropriate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your very unusual specific case.
`LIMU REPS <PROG>`  ONLY in N  transports. 
Then importing the last transport only would be sufficient.
But you need to remove the other transports from the buffer to avoid later out of
sequence import resetting to an earlier version.

Importing ALL of these transports is best practice.
R3TRANS will sort Transport content during an import ALL to get the net effect. 
That only Import last only would have done. The production system doesnt have n interim states when using Import ALL.

Importing the transports individually in the order that they are in the queue is also OK,
but you have the issue about the production state of the program until the last import is committed.

**If in Doubt use IMPORT ALL.**

Of course Import ALL will also import other transports in the queue.
So you must make sure all transports in the queue are tested and ready to go to production.

Importing transports out of order means you must delete the other transports or deal with the issue of out of sequence imports. A recipe for problems waiting to happen.

I have a rule, **Only GOD is allowed to import out of sequence**.
If you are that good and know how R3Import works, and ALL the implications, then go ahead import out of sequence and/or ignore/delete transports.

If not GOD like knowledge then be prepared for Problems.

Comment: Thank you for the response @phil soady

In the same story; what if 3rd request would got an error while transporing to QA ? Should I transport all requests to Prıduction in this sceario as well ? Or should I discard the 3rd. request ?

Comment: even with an error, a follow on transport presumably corrects the error. You have tested that the result of all transports is good, so all transport go. You import them all together and the latest version of the Class or Program is what is finally activated .